# same onTouchListener not working

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I have the exact same code in two different activities (with different xml layouts and different variable names and id's of course)

It's only an imageview matching the parent width/height with an onTouchListener that starts a function on touch.

The same goes for the second activity. (these activities have nothing to do with each other other tahn starting another and killing it self.

```
ImageView wall;
TextView welcome;
Typeface tf;
Sound sound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    sound = new Sound(Start.this);

    welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
    wall = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wall);

    live();
}

private void live()
{
    wall.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    v.setPressed(true);

                     next(); //starts a new activity and kills self (this.finish())

                    break;
                default:
                    v.setPressed(false);
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }

    });
}
```

And then the second activity

```
Sound sound;
ImageView ball;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next1);
    sound = new Sound(next1.this);

    ball = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ball);

    ball.setEnabled(true);
    live();
}

private void live()
{

 //it's calling so far...

 //but the listener wont work
   ball.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    v.setPressed(true);

                    startFunction();

                    break;
                default:
                    v.setPressed(false);
                    break;
            }

            return true;
       }

    });
}
```

And here's a twist, ontouchlistsner or clicklistener or whatever works fine in the first activity, but in the second neither ontouch or onclick work but if i set the onclick in the xml file, it works, wtfisupwiththat...?

EDIT: my xml files. They are pretty much the same too,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipChildren="false"
tools:context=".Start">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff3242"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And next1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipChildren="false"
tools:context=".next1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ball"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#333333"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml of second activity once..

Comment: Do you see any logcat error?

Comment: Nope no errors or anything, the second activity onTouchListener just doesn't get called

Comment: How do you start second activity?

Comment: Like this:

Intent intent = new Intent(this, next1.class);
startActivity(intent);

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeaway);